Creating a pyd module importer from memory
Im facing a problem where i need to load a python dll (pyd) file from memory to be used as a module (basically i want to build a pyd-module-loader)
Importlib has no loader that is suitable to load a library from memory.
I tried using this github repo: https://github.com/naksyn/PythonMemoryModule
Which allows me to load the pyd file as any other pe.
I tried (using this lib) to call the PyInit_x function but my python.exe always crushes right after.
Im using python 3.11.9 if it helps.
Ill appreciate any help on the subject!

what's your OS?

Hey! Windows 11
